# How to make value - same after key in and selected

Tags: javascript

Need help.

I want to make content input are same as keyin when selected and disable dropdown when edit at textarea.

Currently, content will appear after dropdown. When key-in at textarea and select that list, its not appears same as key-in at top when close. After select that list, when try to key-in, dropdown will open. How to disable it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-select', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ul = $(this).find("ul");
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        if (ul.find("li").is(e.target)) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            target.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
            var value = target.html();
            $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
            $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
        }
        ul.hide();
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $('.btn-select').not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
        });
        ul.slideDown(300);
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
 
$('.dropinput').click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```css
.form-control {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #4f5858;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0px;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #b6b6b6;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: 0 none;
}

.close {
    color: #4f5858;
 text-shadow: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 26px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #4f5858;
}

.btn-grey {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #4f5858;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 60px;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline;
}

.btn-grey:hover {
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
 background-color: #f05423;
}

.btn-select {
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-select .btn-select-value {
    padding: 2px 6px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none !important;

}

.btn-select .btn-select-arrow {
    float: right;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    top: 0;
 font-size: 10px;
}

.btn-select ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #4f5858;
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -0.5px;
 left: -1px;
    top: 33px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.btn-select ul li {
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: left;
 background-color: #fff;
 display: flex;
}

.btn-select ul li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
 color: #f05423;
}
.btn-select ul li span {
 color: #b3b3b3;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
}

.btn-select ul li.selected {
    color: #f05423;
}


.btn-select.btn-default:hover, .btn-select.btn-default:active, .btn-select.btn-default.active {
    border-color: #b6b6b6;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-select.btn-default ul li.selected {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-select.btn-default ul, .btn-select.btn-default .btn-select-value {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: #b6b6b6 1px solid;
 border-top: 0px;
}

.btn-default {
    color: #4f5858;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: inone;
}

.btn-default span {
    color: #4f5858;
}
.btn-select.btn-default ul li.selected span {
    color: #4f5858;
}

textarea.form-control {
    height: 100px;
}

.dropinput {
    color: #000;
 background-color: #ebebeb;
 border: none;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 width: 170px;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.oth {
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
          <a class="btn btn-default btn-select">
                <input class="btn-select-input" type="hidden">
                <span class="btn-select-value">Purpose of Enquiry</span>
                <span class="btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li>Media & Publications</li>
                    <li>New Business Collaborations<input maxlength="30" class="dropinput" type="text" placeholder="Please specify project location"></li>
                    <li>Others<input maxlength="58" class="dropinput oth" type="text" placeholder="Please specify"></li>
                </ul>
            </a>
            </div>
```

tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
function init(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-select', function (e) {

        if(document.activeElement==$(this).find('.btn-select-value input')[0]) // prevent opening when textfield is focused
            return

        e.preventDefault();
        var ul = $(this).find("ul");
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            if (ul.find("li").is(e.target)) {
               selectLine(this,$(e.target))
            }
            ul.hide();
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $('.btn-select').not(this).each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
            });
            ul.slideDown(300);
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });

    $('.dropinput').blur(function(e) {
        if(e.currentTarget.value.length==0) // if nothing has been entered, skip
            return
        var dropdown = $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().parent();
        var ul = dropdown.children('ul')
        selectLine(dropdown[0],$(e.currentTarget).parent())
        ul.hide();
        dropdown.removeClass("active");
    });

    $('.dropinput').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}

function selectLine(dropdown,target){
    var input_text = target.find('input').val() // take input value from input in list

    target.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var value = target.html();
    $(dropdown).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
    $(dropdown).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
    $(dropdown).find(".btn-select-value input").val(input_text); // put input value into input in selected input
}

$(document).ready(init)
```

It's quite the spaghetti code, but it works. It's always smart to wrap your code into an init function which will get called once your document is ready.

Comment: my godness.. its take me 1 week.. but u..
Thank you very much sir!